# Sending a var with file, accessing it in script & Displaying a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Currently there is a form in **home.html page** which allows us to submit data. After data is saved, displaying the same .html page but different div (message like - Congrts, your poll is created ....).
For this I am sending a boolean var dataSaved while sending file so that i can retrieve the boolean var & display the div.

I am submitting form like this -

```
<form class="" action="/home/newPoll" method="post">
<form>
```

My **server.js** looks like this -

```
app.post('/home/newPoll', function (req, res) {  
    const newPoll = new PollModel({
    ............//something here
    });
    PollModel(newPoll).save(function(error, data){
          if (error) {
            throw error;
            console.error("User Data is not saved."+error);
          } else {
            console.log("User data saved successfully");// working fine
            res.sendFile(__dirname+'/views/home.html', {dataSaved: true}); // this page is displayed also
          }
        });
    });
```

if this var dataSaved is true, I want to display the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ............// some more code here, are working fine. 
    const dataSaved = <%= dataSaved %>;
    console.log(dataSaved); // not getting this
    if (dataSaved ) {
       $("#newPollDiv").hide();
       $("#myPollDiv").hide();
       $("#pollCreated").show();
    }
}
```

I am not using any view template.

**kindly suggest, also if any other way to do this.**

Comment: How are you sending the form data? Are you using AJAX or are you refreshing the page after you POST the data? If you are refreshing the page, your client will not capture the server's response.

Comment: @CoconutFred post updated. Refreshing the page. please suggest how to do this without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the form data in an AJAX request. Right now it looks like the client isn't receiving your response at all, because you are refreshing the page after POSTing the form data.

Since you're using jQuery, I suggest you read: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Basically, you use the function `$.post` with the URL to send the form data to and a callback to display the divs as inputs.

Example:

```
$.post("/your/api/endpoint", function(response) {
    $("#newPollDiv").hide();
    //...
});
```